# Trying to export multiple textures/materials to .gltf file, but only exporting one texture

Tags: materials, export, gltf

I am trying to export multiple textures applied to an object in blender.
I have the following:[image]

However, when trying to export the gltf file, only one of the materials gets exported.[image]

I am trying to export with the following settings:

[image]
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Is the second material actually applied to the mesh? What happens when you import the glTF back into Blender?

Comment: @scurest how would I apply the material to the mesh?
The only way I am able to actually change the one applied is by changing the image "attached" to the "texture75" in this case. 

When importing the gltf I only had the "texture75" (which was first created)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/517/88681

Comment: @scurest doesn't that allow applying only one texture at the same time?

I tried this and the only one that gets exported is the last one I assigned.

Edit:

I think there might be the possibility you misunderstood my question or i badly explained myself.

I want to be able to use both textures on the mesh, however only want one applied at a time.

Comment: Only materials that are actually used on the mesh are going to be exported, "unused material slots" is not a thing that exists in glTF. Perhaps you'd be interested in material variants though: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#gltf-variants